# How to translate track and rail in French?

Tags: vocabulaire

What would you call *track* and *rail* in French? Track is the whole thing, while rail is a piece of metal e.g. on the right.

You can see an exemple of track on [this picture](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/zL5aEWRzgSt719K4V_TSOdIN49ZTdyGHEB0B0ZX5un-iDIEyJfQ-m0JqhW1f4ytN2Iw=w300), and an exemple of rail [on this one](http://www.ikonet.com/es/diccionariovisual/images/esp/corte-de-un-rail-117780.jpg).

My suggestions are:

track - voie ferrée f

rail - rail m

Thank you.

Comment: Les suggestions sont tout à fait correctes.

Comment: Wikipedia has [an article with pictures](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail) that answers your question.  Dictionaries are also very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed correct in both your statements.

*A track* is translated most of the time by *une voie ferrée*. The error would be to translate it as *chemin de fer*, which is itself composed of one or more *voies ferrées*. It can also be called *une ligne de chemin de fer* if the railroad only has one track.

*A rail* is translated as *un rail*.